# Print only one result of a query using PHP and mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I am working with mySQL and PHP and I came across a query that is making think for the entire day, I'm not sure if my difficulties are with not knowing some advance command that might be requested for this, can you please help?

Here's the thing: I am working with an old database and I don't want to change the tables in it, so I got to work with two tables:

- album: this table has only two fields, id_album and album_name;
- photos: this table holds the photo's paths and it's linked to the album table by the field id_album;

I want to build a page that will list all the albums and each one will have a thumbnail, that I'm taking from the "photos" table, in that case, I need to list just one photo to each album, and I'm not sure how to write the code for that, this is what I got so far:

```
  <?php

  $comando = "SELECT * FROM album";

    $consulta = mysql_query($comando, $database)

        or die('Error:<br/>'.$comando);

    while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {


        $comando1 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE album = '".$dados['id_album']."'";
        $consulta1 = mysql_query($comando1, $database)
        or die('Error'.$comando1);

        while($dados1= mysql_fetch_array($consulta1)){          
          print '<li><a href="photos.php?Cod='.$dados['id_album'].'"><img src="'.$dados1['foto'].'"/></a><br/><a href="photos.php?Cod='.$dados['id_album'].'"> ' .$dados['album_name']. '</a></li>';

    }}

    ?>
```

It is working correctly but it is listing all photos in all albums. Is there a way that I can make it print just one photo for each album?

Thank you very very much in advance!

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? 
`mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Please show the structure of your `album` table. Also, which photo do you want to see per album - first, last, random, smallest, etc?

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that mysql_query is becoming obsolete, I worked with it a very long time ago and I am just starting to go back to programming, so I very much appreciate the tutorial you sent me! I will sure start to update my skills!

Answer (score 1):

```
$comando1 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE album = '".$dados['id_album']."' LIMIT 1";
```

You should JOIN the queries. Use something like

```
$comando = "
   SELECT album.id_album, photos.* FROM `album` 
   LEFT JOIN `photos` on photos.album = album.id_album
   GROUP BY album.id_album";
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help, I didn't know the existance of "LIMIT" such a simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {

$comando1 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE album = '".$dados['id_album']."' LIMIT 1 order by rand()";
$consulta1 = mysql_query($comando1, $database) or die('Error'.$comando1);

$dados1= mysql_fetch_row($consulta1);        
print '<li><a href="photos.php?Cod='.$dados['id_album'].'"><img src="'.$dados1['foto'].'"/></a><br/><a href="photos.php?Cod='.$dados['id_album'].'"> ' .$dados['album_name']. '</a></li>';

}
```

But you should really use MySqli or something else ..

Comment: Thank you very much!! 

I just have another question for you, I used the mysql_fetch_row and it didn't work, I switched to mysql_fetch_array for testing and it worked, do you have any idea why?

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you use a single query with `GROUP_CONCAT` to get photos of album and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to pick one photo

```
SELECT a.* ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(p.foto),',',1) AS foto
FROM album a
LEFT JOIN photos p ON(a.id_album = p.id_album)
GROUP BY a.id_album
```

You can also specify `ORDER BY` in `GROUP_CONCAT` by your auto increment column in photos table to pick latest or first one as `GROUP_CONCAT(p.foto ORDER BY p.id DESC)`.Also as tadman mentioned in comments you are using depreciated `mysql_*` family functions better to start with PDO

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=dbname', 'user', 'pass');
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT a.* ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(p.foto),',',1) AS foto
FROM album a
LEFT JOIN photos p ON(a.id_album = p.id_album)
GROUP BY a.id_album
");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(); 

foreach($result as $res){

  echo '<li><a href="photos.php?Cod='.$res['id_album'].'"><img src="'.$res['foto'].'"/></a><br/><a href="photos.php?Cod='.$res['id_album'].'"> ' .$res['album_name']. '</a></li>';
}
?>
```

[`PDO::errorInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Also during development you should care for errors before execute

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false); 
if (!$sth) { 
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n"; 
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo()); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much!!! 

I stopped using mySQL and PHP for 5 years so I'm glad I've posted my doubt here so you guys could show me how much I need to update my studies on it! Thank you very much for your help!!